# Can I get current user's access/id token from SuiteScript?

Tags: https, openid-connect, netsuite, suitescript

I'm doing some discovery with NetSuite but am struggling to find a way to get the currently logged in user's NetSuite access or id token.

Use case is I want to call an external API (that I'm creating) from SuiteScript. I have decided to use the https module in a User Event Script when a record is created. I want to include the NetSuite access or id token in the Authorization header with this request.

I understand that I can use NetSuite as an OIDC provider which means I can access the public keys for my account via JWKS URL and validate the NetSuite token, verify user role etc. and permit the operation. Therefore securing my external API.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can get data on the current User by Using the N/runtime module.
[Typescript import and examples of use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4Soy.png)

Comment: I see the data you can get, but nothing about their NetSuite auth token
https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_4296359529.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).